# BASH: importing data from flat file into template

Tags: perl, bash, templates, text-processing, template-toolkit

I have a flat file of records, each 33 lines long. I need to format this file to specs in a template. The template is in DOS format while the source file is in NIX format. The template has specific indenting and spacing which must be adhered to. I've thought of a few options:

- BASH with classic nix tools: sed, awk, grep etc...
- BASH with template toolkit
- Perl eith template toolkit
- Perl

These are in order of my familiarity. Here's a sample source record ( NIX format ):
I've reduced the number of newlines to save space ( normally 33 lines ):

```
JACKSON HOLE SANITARIUM AND REPTILE ZOO
45 GREASY HOLLER LN
JACKSON HOLE, AK   99999


Change Service Requested


BUBBA HOTEP
3 DELIVERANCE RD
MINNEAPOLIS, MN   99998


BUBBA HOTEP 09090909090909

You have a hold available for pickup as of 2012-01-04:

Title: Banjo for Fun and Profit
Author: Williams, Billy Dee
Price: $10
```

Here's the template ( DOS format -- lines reduced - 66 lines normally):

```
     <%BRANCH-NAME%>
     <%BRANCH-ADDR%>
     <%BRANCH-CTY%>


<%CUST-NAME%> <%BARCODE%>
You have a hold available for pickup as of <%DATE%>:

Title: <%TITLE%>
Author: <%AUTHOR%>
Price: <%PRICE%>


             <%CUST-NAME%>
             <%CUST-ADDR%>
             <%CUST-CTY%>

end of file
```

It actually does say "end of file" at the end of each record.

Thoughts? I tend to over-complicate things.

**UPDATE2**

Figured it out.

My answer is below. Feel free to suggest improvements.

Comment: Maybe use PHP from the command line? If done right, it gives you a resuable component for a future web interface for free ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Eugen, but I won't be webify-ing this stuff and I don't know PHP.

Comment: When you say `format a file to specs in template` what exactly do you wish to do with your file containing records?

Comment: I need format the records to match the template record. My idea was to first create template ( done ), second pull each record out of the file, input it to template, last concatenate formatted records to new file.

Comment: There may be a simpler method to do this. I don't want to lead people to my convoluted method. If a person format it in place in a simple way ...

Comment: Will post code later this afternoon. Thanks.

Comment: Perl *is* a classic unix tool.

Comment: You're right ...but late 80's. Sed, awk and grep pre-date. A technicality though, you're right. If you have a better way than my bash above ...in perl ...I'll thank you. My perl sucks eggs or I'd try perl.

Comment: Does your record have a starting identifier that we can use to mark start of a record. Ending won't be a problem since every record is 33 lines. Will that be a safe assumption?

Comment: @JaypalSingh. Starting identifier would be a regex on LOCATION. Ending identifier is /Price:/.

Comment: Thanks and your record file shows customer name, address etc before the customer name, barcode and Title, author, price. Is that how it should be?

Comment: Actually, reverse that. Customer name and barcode first. Customer address last. Location info is first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I am using for this project. Feel free to suggest improvements, or, submit better solutions.

```
cp $FILE $WORKING # we won't mess with original

NUM_RECORDS=$( grep "^Price:" "$FILE" | wc -l ) # need to know how many records we have 
                                              # counting occurences of end of record r

TMP=record.txt # holds single record, used as temp storage in loop below

# Sanity
# Make sure temp storage exists. If not create -- if so, clear it.
[ ! -f $TMP ] && touch $TMP || cat /dev/null >$TMP

# functions
function make_template () {
    local _file="$1"
    mapfile -t filecontent < "$_file"
    _loc_name="${filecontent[0]}"
    _loc_strt="${filecontent[1]}"
    _loc_city="${filecontent[2]}"
    _pat_name="${filecontent[14]}"
    _pat_addr="${filecontent[15]}"
    _pat_city="${filecontent[16]}"
    _barcode=${filecontent[27]:(-14)} # pull barcode from end of string
    _date=${filecontent[29]:(-11)}    # pull date from end of string
    # Test title length - truncate if necessary - 70 chars.
    _title=$(grep -E "^Title:" $_file)
    MAXLEN=70
    [ "${#_title}" -gt "$MAXLEN" ] && _title="${filecontent[31]:0:70}" || :
    _auth=$(grep -E "^Author:" $_file)
    _price=$(grep -E "^Price:" $_file)
    sed "
        s@<%BRANCH-NAME%>@${_loc_name}@g
        s@<%BRANCH-ADDR%>@${_loc_strt}@g
        s@<%BRANCH-CTY%>@${_loc_city}@g
        s@<%CUST-NAME%>@${_pat_name}@g
        s@<%CUST-ADDR%>@${_pat_addr}@
        s@<%CUST-CTY%>@${_pat_city}@
        s@<%BARCODE%>@${_barcode}@g
        s@<%DATE%>@${_date}@
        s@<%TITLE%>@${_title}@
        s@<%AUTHOR%>@${_auth}@
        s@<%PRICE%>@${_price}@" "$TEMPLATE"
}

####################################
#  MAIN
####################################

for((i=1;i<="$NUM_RECORDS";i++))
do
    sed -n '1,/^Price:/{p;}' "$WORKING" >"$TMP"  # copy first record with end of record
                                                # and copy to temp storage.

    sed -i '1,/^Price:/d' "$WORKING"             # delete first record using EOR regex.
    make_template "$TMP"                        # send temp file/record to template fu
done

# cleanup
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

As a starter, here is a hint: Perl HERE-documents (showing just a few substitutions as a demo):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines = qw/branchname cust_name barcode bogus whatever/; # (<>);

my ($branchname, $cust_name, $barcode, undef, $whatever) = @lines;

print <<TEMPLATE;
     $branchname
     <%BRANCH-ADDR%>
     <%BRANCH-CTY%>


$cust_name $barcode
You have a hold available for pickup as of <%DATE%>:

Title: <%TITLE%>
Author: <%AUTHOR%>
Price: <%PRICE%>


             $cust_name
             <%CUST-ADDR%>
             <%CUST-CTY%>

end of file
TEMPLATE
```

Replace the dummy input array with the lines read from the stdin with `(<>)` if you will. (Use a loop reading `n` lines and push it to the array if that is more efficient). I just showed the gist, add more variables as required, and skip input lines by specifting `undef` for the 'capture' variable (as shown).

Now, simply interpolate these variables into your text.

If line-ends are giving you any grief, consider using `chomp` eg.:

```
my @lines = (<>); # just read em all...
my @cleaned = map { chomp } @lines;
```

Comment: added a little more hints on how to go forward from this

Comment: The template part would need to be removed from the code to make it reusable for other templates. Am going to work with this.